# How to aggregate QuerySet based on property of model?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

For example some model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    a = models.FloatField()
    b = models.FloatField()

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.a / self.b
```

And we want to find minimal value in QuerySet:

```
bar = Foo.objects.aggregate(Min('c'))
```

But this doesn't work, because `c` not in database and can't be fetched from db. How to get minimum value `c` of `Foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the logic inside the query itself instead of as a property that is evaluated in Python.  Something like this should work:

```
from django.db.models import F, Min

bar = Foo.objects.annotate(c=F('a') / F('b')).aggregate(Min('c'))
```